# Windows SMTP: Script Outbound Security

Tags: windows, powershell, smtp, wmi

Building a config script in PowerShell to configure web servers' SMTP service to use the AWS SES (simple email service) for [outbound mail delivery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-windows-server.html). Easy to do manually, but as we enter a load-balanced world, I'm having a helluva time getting it scripted.

My main challenge seems to be turning on Basic Auth and providing the creds. I can't seem to figure out what WMI fields those might be... I'm thinking the cred fields are `RouteUserName` and `RoutePassword`, but can't seem to find the right option to turn on BasicAuth to prove that. Checking the TLS encryption box is evading me as well.

Am I missing something obvious or just not using the right variables?

Fields I'm struggling with illustrated:
[image]

Sample script that I've built so far. Relay IP works and the RouteUserName and RoutePassword fields are confirmed set. But what are the rest?

```
$smtpuser = Get-SSMParameter -Name SMTP_User
$smtppass = Get-SSMParameter -Name SMTP_Password -WithDecryption $true
$smtpfqdn = "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"

$SmtpConfig = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -ComputerName localhost -Query "Select * From IisSmtpServerSetting"
$RelayIpList = @( 24, 0, 0, 128, 32, 0, 0, 128, 60, 0, 0, 128, 68, 0, 0, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 0, 0, 1 )
$SmtpConfig.RelayIPList = $RelayIPList
$SmtpConfig.AllowAnonymous = $false
$SmtpConfig.AuthBasic = $true
$SmtpConfig.RouteUserName = $smtpuser.Value
$SmtpConfig.RoutePassword = $smtppass.Value
$SmtpConfig.AlwaysUseSsl = $true
$SmtpConfig.DefaultDomain = $smtpfqdn
$SmtpConfig.SmartHost = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"

$SmtpConfig.Put()

Restart-Service "SMTPSVC" -ErrorAction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with much experimentation. Here's the pertinent bits of my script. Note that I'm keeping the SMTP user creds stored in AWS Systems Manager parameter store.

```
$smtpuser = Get-SSMParameter -Name SMTP_User
$smtppass = Get-SSMParameter -Name SMTP_Password -WithDecryption $true
$smtpfqdn = "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"

Set-Service "SMTPSVC" -StartupType Automatic -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Service "SMTPSVC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$SmtpConfig = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -ComputerName localhost -Query "Select * From IisSmtpServerSetting"
$RelayIpList = @( 24, 0, 0, 128, 32, 0, 0, 128, 60, 0, 0, 128, 68, 0, 0, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 0, 0, 1 )
$SmtpConfig.RelayIPList = $RelayIPList
$SmtpConfig.AuthFlags = "1"
$SmtpConfig.AuthBasic = $false
$SmtpConfig.RouteAction = "268"
$SmtpConfig.RouteUserName = $smtpuser.Value
$SmtpConfig.RoutePassword = $smtppass.Value
$SmtpConfig.AlwaysUseSsl = $true
$SmtpConfig.SmartHostType = "2"
$SmtpConfig.DefaultDomain = $smtpfqdn
$SmtpConfig.SmartHost = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
$SmtpConfig.RemoteSmtpPort = "587"

$SmtpConfig.Put()

Restart-Service "SMTPSVC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```